# How to display subcategory related to category using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to display subcategory to related category in this menu firsrt category has been displayed but  i have to  display subcatory to relate category ?

**Database**

[category table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCXiN.png)

[front page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7HXE.png)

**controller**

```php
public function index(){
     $category=DB::table('category')->where('p_id',0)->get();
     return view('front_end/index',compact('category'));
}
```

**html view**

```html
            <div class="nav-panel__nav-links nav-links">
            <ul class="nav-links__list">
            @foreach($category as $firstmenu)
               <li class="nav-links__item  nav-links__item--has-submenu ">
                <a id="cate" class="nav-links__item-link" href=" 
               {{$firstmenu->cate_name}}">
               <div class="nav-links__item-body">
               {{$firstmenu->cate_name}}
               <svg class="nav-links__item-arrow" width="9px" height="6px">
                <use xlink:href="public/assets/images/sprite.svg#arrow-rounded-down-9x6"></use>
                </svg>
                </div>
                </a>
                 <div class="nav-links__submenu nav-links__submenu--type--megamenu nav-links__submenu-- 
                 size--nl">
                   <!-- .megamenu -->
                   <div class="megamenu ">
                   <div class="megamenu__body">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-6">
                        <ul class="megamenu__links megamenu__links--level--0">
                           <li class="megamenu__item  megamenu__item--with-submenu ">
                                  /sub category /
                              <a href="">T-shirts</a>
                              <ul class="megamenu__links megamenu__links--level--1">
                                       /sub category /                               
                                 <li class="megamenu__item"><a href="">short paint</a>
                                 </li>
                              </ul>
                           </li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <!-- .megamenu / end -->
         </div>
      </li>
      @endforeach
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you also show us your model? Could be usefull for us to know the relations.

Comment: actully i  did not create any model for category  just  fatch data using  DB class how to do ?

Comment: do u limit the categories level, I means how deep it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so at first you need to fetch this subcategory somehow. You can use eloquent relationship if defined or simple join like so:

DB query:

```
$category = DB::table('category')                                              
           ->join('subcategory', 'subcategory.category_id', '=','category.id') 
           ->where('p_id',0)                                                
           ->get();
```

Eloquent(if category have more than one subcategory):

Category Model:

```
public function subcategory()
{
    return $this->hasMany(SubCategory::class, 'category_id', 'id');
}
```

Controller

```
$category = Category::with('subcategory')->get();
```

And then just get the name or some other value of subcategory in view (**important** - if there could be more subcategories related to your category than just one you have to use loop to itereate through all subcategories):

```
 {{$category->subcategory->name}}
```

Or

```
@foreach($category->subcategory as $sub_cat)
   {{$sub_cat->name}}
@endforeach
```

For more informations you should check Laravel documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 1):

As you have posted the table structure

Your relationship will be like

```
  public function subCategories(){
        return $this->hasMany(SELF::class, 'p_id', 'id');
    }

    public function parentCategories(){
        return $this->hasMany(SELF::class, 'p_id', 'id');
    }

   public scopeParent($query){
       return $query->whereNull('p_id');
   }
   public scopeChild($query){
       return $query->whereNotNull('p_id');
   }
```

And you should be able to get the categories like

```
$categories = Category::parent()->get();
```

and then something like this

```
foreach($categories->with('subCategories')->get() as $category) {
   foreach($category->subCategories as $subCategory) {
    }
}
```